# Client not connecting to our C# web service from java client

Tags: c#, web-services

I've developed a C# Web-service using VS 2012 .net 4.0.

We're having problems with our client connecting to it.

I have custom logging in the web-service and it logs into a SQL table both successes and failures. The client is submitting XML. But the client calls never reach the web service best as I can tell.

I'm able to connect from outside using a C# client I developed so I know the issue is not the firewall because the server is publicly available. During these calls my internal logging works fine.

More importantly the client reports their returned error as..."Response Code=500 Response Message=Internal Server Error". So it looks like it's reaching the server but not the web service.

I've looked at the IIS log but I'm not to knowledgeable about it so I thought I'd ask here.

Here's an examples of what's in the IIS logs for his client call which doesn't actually trigger my web service...

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2013-12-12 03:37:41
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2013-12-12 03:37:41 172.16.20.40 POST /FAResults/FAResults.asmx - 80 - 172.16.20.204 Jakarta+Commons-HttpClient/3.1 500 0 0 577
```

And here's the IIS log entry for my C# client app call which does trigger my web service...

```
2013-12-16 20:18:34 172.16.20.40 POST /FAResults/FAResults.asmx - 80 - 172.16.20.204 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.7905) 200 0 0 10030
```

Can anyone guide me as to where to look for a solution?

Comment: What technology did you use to create the web service?

Comment: Does your C# client do a GET and the Java one, a POST?

Comment: Daniel, I'm not sure. I created a Web Service using VS 2012 in C#...I don't remember having to do anything other than write the code within the method and then publish it to my server.  I was then able to call it from a client.

Comment: Moo-Juice, what's the best way to determine that?

Comment: Moo-Juice it looks like we're both using POST...I'll add the log entry from a successful call from my client in my original post above...

Comment: Can you capture both requests in Fiddler? I suspect the content of the two POST requests are different.